# How to achieve this effect while listview is loading with items in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Lately, this kind of effect is gaining lot of popularity.
While items are being populated, listview shows this kind of affect.
What exactly is this and how can one implement it.
Thanks!

[image: ListView loadiing effect in android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [LoaderViewLibrary](https://github.com/elye/loaderviewlibrary) on Github.

The description matches your requirements -

> Library that enables TextView of ImageView to show loading animation
>   while waiting for the text and image get loaded

Comment: No problem ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy layout exactly similar to what you want o show on pre-loading and then set it to listView on Empaty method,like this.

```
View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view); 
 listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to achive loading effect.

// Gradle dependency on Shimmer for Android

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
}
```

Official documentation [Shimmer Effect](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/)